# Links and book about MQFTE?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, file-transfer, websphere-7, websphere-mq-fte

Hi I am working with MQFTE. I need to know more in detail about how mqfte works and what are the internal process that takes place during a operation.

The IBM links about mqfte/red books is good , but it doesn't have in depth contents.

Could you please suggest me some links/ebooks to know more about mqfte and mq?.

Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not too many 3rd party links and the only books I am aware of are the few Redbooks.  However, this will be a start:

[WebSphere MQ FTE Home Page](http://ibm.co/qwnImU)
[WebSphere MQ FTE Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)
[WebSphere MQ FTE Fix List](http://ibm.co/pNIp3o)
IBM Redbook: [Getting Started with WebSphere MQ FTE](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247760.html)

[WebSphere training](http://ibm.co/r0YaBN) (Including WMQ FTE)

[WebSphere MQ product page](http://ibm.co/oHFS06)
[WebSphere MQ v7 documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)
[WebSphere MQ v6 documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp)
[WebSphere MQ Requirements](http://ibm.co/nrlrb2)
[WebSphere MQ Recommended Fixes](http://ibm.co/nGM3oE)
[WebSphere MQ SupportPacs](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs)
[Websphere MQ 6+ Certification Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842484/websphere-mq-6-certification-book) - Links to resources for self-study

developerWorks article [Securing WebSphere MQ FTE](http://ibm.co/g8l0fY)
developerWorks [Mission:Messaging](http://ibm.co/MisMesIndx) column has in-depth articles on some of the trickier areas of WebSphere MQ family products.

[T-Rob.net](http://t-rob.net) has a collection of WMQ security info, links, articles and all back-episodes of *The Deep Queue* podcast.